# Web table is taking more time to load by the time another element is clicked how to handle the wait in selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-java

Managing the delay in loading a web table before clicking another element

The web table exhibits a prolonged loading time, necessitating the implementation of a wait strategy in Selenium (Java) to ensure its complete rendering before proceeding to interact with another element.

```
public static void saveAndContinues(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    // Wait for the "Continue" button to be clickable
    WebElement continueButton =         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(GENERIC_CONTINUE_BUTTON));

    // Check if the table loading indicator is present
    WebElement loadingIndicator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='yourproducts'][2]"));
    if (loadingIndicator.isDisplayed()) {
        // Continue waiting if the table is still loading
        WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        // You can add additional conditions if needed
        throw new RuntimeException("Table is still loading");
    }

    // Click on the "Continue" button
    continueButton.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having a method similar to this one:

```
    public static void waitForElementToNotBePresent(By locator, int maxTimeout, int waitPeriod) throws InterruptedException {
        int currentTimeout = 0;

        while (currentTimeout < maxTimeout) {
            try {
                // if element is found, it means the loading process is still not finished
                Driver.driver.findElement(locator);
                currentTimeout += waitPeriod;
                Thread.sleep(waitPeriod);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
                // if element is not found, the loading process is finished
                return;
            }
        }

        // if we reach this point, the loading process did not finish in the given time
        // otherwise we might end in an infinite loop
        throw new TimeoutException("Loading did not finish in the given time");
    }
```

It would allow you to have a long wait for the element to disappear but it would also check regularly for it's presence.

With this method your code would look something like this:

```
waitForElementToNotBePresent(By.xpath("//*[@id='yourproducts'][2]"), 60000, 1000);
continueButton.click();
```

Comment: used these methos without Thread.sleep but still its throwing loading did not finish in the given time

Comment: What do you mean you used the methods without `Thread.sleep`? It is a necessary part of this method as the method has to actually wait, to stop the process and wait, otherwise it would just increment fast and fail as the loading obviously would not have finished. How long does the loading take approximately from your observations?

Comment: Furthermore if you would look at your original code, you are defining the `wait1` object, but you do not call any method on it. The fact that you have created a `WebDriverWait` object with duration of 30 seconds does not mean that it will actually wait for 30 seconds, because you are not calling any method that would try to do some searching and wait for the results to be present.